# 2004 KIA Sedona Timing Belt Replacement

Tags: timing-belt, kia, water-pump

I am planning a Timing Belt / Water pump Replacement on a 2004 Kia sedona.  I would like to know for the people who may have done a job like this .  was there any special tools you required.  If so were they available for rent?
thanks
Reid Lantz

Comment: if i empty the whole system of antifreeze how much typically to refill.   2-3 gallons???

Comment: It is in section 8 of the owner's manual, under capacities. It holds 8.2 liters, or 2.2 gallons. This is an example why you need a service manual for this job.

Answer (score 2):

I have not done this job on this engine specifically, but I can answer your question from experience with similar jobs. In researching this job, I did not find any "special" tools specific to Kia, or this engine.

Other than standard tools and supplies, this is what you will need;

1. Service manual

Regardless of experience level, a service manual is invaluable in situations like this. It will give you the important information needed to do the job properly.

2. Camshaft holding/locking tool

This is not a specific tool for Kias. It is a common tool used to hold the camshafts in time while you install the belt. **Timing is critical to the engines ability to run properly, so make sure you do this part correctly.** There are many varieties of this tool and may or may not be available for rent at your parts store.

[image]

---

[image]

3. Belt Tension Adjuster Tool

This tool is used to hold the tension pull out of the way while removing and installing the belt. It may or may not be available for rent at your parts store.

[image]